# Conditional calculation based on other columns lagged values

Tags: r, if-statement, time-series, conditional-statements

Newbie: I have a dataset where I want to calculate the y-o-y growth of sales of a company. The dataset contains approx. 1000 companies with each different number of years listed on a public stock exchange. The data looks like this:

```
#      gvkey fyear at    company name
#22    17436 2010  59393 BASF SE
#23    17436 2011  61175 BASF SE
#24    17436 2012  64327 BASF SE
       ...
#30    17436 2018  86556 BASF SE
#31    17828 1989  62737 DAIMLER AG
#32    17828 1990  67339 DAIMLER AG
#33    17828 1991  75714 DAIMLER AG
       ...
#60    17828 2018  281619  DAIMLER AG
```

I would like to create a new column `growth` where I calculate the percentage increase of `at` from e.g. BASF SE (gvkey 17436) from 2010 to 2011, to 2012 and so on. In row #31 the conditional statement is supposed to work that it would not calculate the increase based on values that belong to BASF but rather have a NA value. Therefore the next value in this new column "growth" in row 32 would be the percentage increase of DAIMLER (gvkey 17828) from 62727 to 67339

So far I tried:

```
if TA$gvkey == lag(TA$gvkey) {mutate(TA, growth = (at - lag(at))/lag(at))} else {NULL}
```

Basically I tried to condition the calculation on the change of the gvkey identifier as this makes the most sense to me. I believe there is a nicer way of maybe running a loop until the gvkey changes and the continue with the next set of values - but I simply don't know how to code that.

I am very new to R and quite lost. I would appreciate every support! Thank you, guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a way to do this in one line. Assuming you data is called data you may try:

```
for(i in data$gvkey){
  a = subset(data,data$gvkey==i)  # a now contains the data of one company
  # calculate pairwise relative difference (assumes sorted years!)
  rel_diff = diff(a)/head(a,-1)   #diff computes pariwise difference and divide by a ( head(a,-1) removes the last element)
  a$growth = c(0,rel_diff) # extend data frame by result, first difference is 0
  #output tro somewhere
}
```

This is a solution with r-base. There might be more efficient ways but this is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the group_by function in dplyr is a good tool to use.By group_by() ing your gv column you will segment out your mutate() call to apply separately for each distinct value of gv. Here is a quick example I made with some dummy data and your same column values:

```
library(dplyr)

dummyData = 
  data.frame(gvkey = c(111,111,111,222,222,222), 
             fyear = c(2010,2012,2011,2010,2011,2013), 
             at =c(2,4,2,4,5,10)
             )

dummyDataTransformed = dummyData %>% 
  group_by(gvkey) %>% 
  arrange(fyear) %>% #to make sure we are chronologically in order
  mutate(growth = at/lag(at,1) -1) %>% #subtract 1 to get year over year change
  ungroup() #I like to ungroup just to make sure i'm not bugging out any calculations I might add further down the line
```